# How can I edit multiple lines with a specific pattern?

Tags: regular-expression

I have a `*.txt` file with 10,000 lines. The lines are E-Mail and password divided by a ":", so like

```
E-Mail:Password
```

I want to delete the E-Mail addresses on every single line at once, so I end up with  the passwords only. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is for later processing, `awk` may be a better tool for automation.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
:%s/^[^:]*://
```

Matches from the start of the line all not-`:` until the first `:` and replaces them with nothing.

Comment: I am using GVIM. When i open the text file and do what you said, it just starts editing the text file. Would you be so kind and could give me like a step by step explation? I'm kinda overwhelmed  by this software and don't want to spend 5 hours reading tutorials. Might as well go ahead then and do it by hand, would be faster probably! :D

Comment: @Marcel This particular command should start with a colon `:` so that it runs a command rather than "normal" keys. I would recommend starting with `vimtutor` to get a basic idea of the different modes, and how to exit and whatnot.

Comment: @Marcel Added leading colon.

Answer (score 1):

Ralf's answer is great. Here's another way you could do it as well:

```
:%norm df:
```

`:%norm` means type the following keys on every line. `df:` means **d**elete until your **f**ind the next **':'**.

Comment: That worked, but now i have all those : at the beginning. I have to get rid of them as well, but the following character is different in every line.

Comment: @Marcel Sorry, my bad. See my edit.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Been sitting here since 2 hours scratching my head. Thank you very much!